# Setting panel's scrollbars position relative to selected children

Tags: c#, winforms, position, panel, scrollbars

I'm developing [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) app. I have a `Panel` control with multiple child controls inside (some of them are placed in the invisible area of panel which has `AutoScroll = true`). Is it possible to set `Panel`'s scrollbars position relative to one of his children? For example, after `Button` click scrollbars are set in proper position to show control which was hided in previous scrollbars position (because control was in invisible area)?

I tried with `panel.HorizontalScroll/VerticalScroll.Value` but I can't find any relation between this value and children location.

Comment: Thanks for reply, here you are: http://pastebin.com/b6ev3ymy (i tried to paste only Form1 constructor here but it was too long).

Comment: `panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(child1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Loathing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904156/loathing)'s comment, I modified your code. I have made the `panel1` an instance variable instead of declaring it in the constructor, as it has to be accessed in `butShowChild1_Click`. Also, `butShowChild1` is not added to the panel. I added it to the panel.

**Modified Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox child1 = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox child2 = new PictureBox();
    Panel panel1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Size = new Size(539, 448);

        panel1 = new Panel();
        panel1.Size = new Size(this.Width - 30, this.Height - 50);
        panel1.AutoScroll = true;

        this.Controls.Add(panel1);

        child1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        child1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        child1.Location = new Point(500, 500);          //child1 will be invisible after run due to it's position
        panel1.Controls.Add(child1);

        child2.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        child2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        child2.Location = new Point(10, 10);           //child2 will be visible after run
        panel1.Controls.Add(child2);

        Button butShowChild1 = new Button() { Location = new Point(70, 70), Text = "Bring Control Into View", AutoSize = true };
        panel1.Controls.Add(butShowChild1);
        butShowChild1.Click += butShowChild1_Click;
    }

    private void butShowChild1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set panel1 scrollbars position to make child1 visible            
        panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(child1);
    }
}
```